# password_verify always returns false

Tags: php, passwords

I've been playing around with this for the last hour and cannot find the solution. I've searched similar questions but none of them were able to give me a solution. I've made sure the lengths of hash is 60 when put into the database and when called from the database. I've omitted much of my code to use up less space. Assume everything works except for password_verify.

Here is my code when a user registers.

```
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    // echo strlen($hash); output is 60

    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=ps', 'ah','je');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, location, activation_code, hash)"
          . "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);

    $n = $query->execute(array($username, $first_name,
    $last_name, $email, $phone_number, $location, $activate_code, $hash));
```

All the values including the hash are stored in the database. Hash has a setting of varchar(100). This is the code that runs when a user tries to log in.

```
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=ps', 'ah','je');
    $sql = "SELECT id, hash FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
    $brigga = $query->execute(array($username));

    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $hash = $row['hash']; //strlen($hash); output is 60
    $user_id = $row['id'];

    if (password_verify($password, $hash))
    {
        return $user_id;
    }
    else 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

The code keep returning false and its driving me crazy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `username` unique in your database? Is there any possibility that your test data is faulty and contains 2 users with `$username`? You only fetch the first row, so I would start by verifying the data.

Comment: `trim()` your password to make sure there is no trailing space

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski. All usernames are unique or else they do not enter the databse

Comment: Post the code where you set the variable `$password` in input before `INSERT`. I suspect it is simple like `$password = $_POST['password']` but perhaps the input variable never contains what you expect prior to hashing and storing.

Comment: check your passwords which stored in database. are they stored completely.

Comment: Another possible factor is due to the column length not being long enough to accomodate the hash; check that and that it is indeed VARCHAR. You could be off by 1 bit. Also make sure your form elements are named and no typos or lettercase mix.

Comment: Another thing; try changing `$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` to `$row = $brigga->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and `SELECT id, hash FROM users WHERE username = ?` to `SELECT id, username, hash FROM users WHERE username = ?`

Comment: 60 for password length isn't enough. I recommend you increase that to 70, or as I do; 255.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ^^ "_Hash has a setting of varchar(100)_"  so the DB column should be sufficient.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Ah, you're right Michael. I didn't see that one. I saw *I've made sure the lengths of hash is 60*. My mistake.